# Converting a Move in Pascal to the equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, pascal

I don't know Pascal and I have a line of code that needs to be translated.  I don't quite understand the designation of the arrays.  It seems to me that the array index in this code refers to the number of elements. It would need to since otherwise I would be move only one element.  Here is the line of code

```
Move(Filter[HALF_FILTER_SIZE], Filter[FftSize-HALF_FILTER_SIZE], HALF_FILTER_SIZE * SizeOf(TComplex));
```

where Filter is an array of size 16384, half filter size is 128, fftsize is 16384 and TComplex is the number of doubles(?) making up one element in the array (complex number). Can someone explain please?
Thanks

Comment: question.. do you know Delphi ? have a look at the Delphi link here Delphi if you are not aware is `Object Oriented Pascal` as well as it's own Objected oriented language http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Move

Comment: The syntax of `Move` can be found at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Move. The code appears to be shifting the array content by the size of an element (as in insertion or deletion of an element).

Comment: @KenWhite seems that c# equivalent is [Array.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, just got confused there.  All ok

Comment: @MethodMan, delphibasics site is the same as W3Schools for web developers. It's utterly outdated and wrong on many places. Take for instance the `Move` example. The `Move` procedure was never intended to be the function for copying strings. It's a low level function for copying raw memory blocks. Of course the example fails on Unicode Delphi because the size of a char is not 1, but 2 bytes. Well, one could use it for this purpose, but there should have been passed `CountOfCharsToCopy * SizeOf(Char)` to the byte count parameter. But we should avoid linking to delphibasics, IMHO.